# Remove duplicate entries from a list and keep last updated entry LocalDate

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, distinct-values

I have an employee class with the following fields.

```
class Employee {
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final LocalDate updatedDate;
    // setters and getters
}
```

I have a list of employee, the list could contain duplicate employees with different `updatedDate`. Now I want to create a set in such a way that it has a unique entry for each `employeeId`. if there are duplicate entries, the one which has the latest `updatedDate` should be kept.

I came up with the below solution, sort based on `updatedDate` and add it `TreeSet` which maintains uniqueness on `Id`. I could use `HashSet` by implementing hashcode & equals in Employee.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

// sort
List<Employee> sortedList = employees.stream()
       .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(employee -> employee.updatedDate)))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing( employee -> employee.id));
sortedList.forEach(employeeSet::add);
```

Now the problem, most of the time employee list will hold unique elements. very rarely there will be duplicate entries. Sorting when only unique entries are present will not scale well. is there a way to improve upon the above solution by avoiding sorting?

Comment: stream has a `distinct()` function that you should check out.... sort by employee id, then the timestamp desc.. then call the distinct()

Comment: This only works if the .equals() implementation doesn't include the updated date though

Comment: You are not using a `TreeMap`, it's a `TreeSet` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way for this question is by using `groupingBy` collector and then use `collectingAndThen` collector to find the latest `updatedDate`.
I think this way is more readable and clean.

for simplifying I imported collectors as static.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

Collection<Employee> collection = employees.stream()
         .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getId,
             collectingAndThen(maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getUpdatedDate)),
                            employee -> employee.orElse(null)))).values();
```

and then

```
List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>(collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer can further simplify as

```
 Collection<Employee> collection = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee:: getId, Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee:: getUpdatedDate)))).values();
```